# How to Truncate a Double in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, truncate

I have a variable in VBA that I need to truncate to 4 significant figures. I can't seem to find anything that won't round the number up or down. But I just want to remove the numbers after the 4th significant figure. I've tried,

```
compressibility = round(compress, -3 - (Int(Log(Abs(compress)))))
```

It removes the numbers after the 4th digit but it still rounds the number up.

Compress is a number around 0.000245848385 as an example, and I need the compressibility number to be 0.0002458.

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks.

Comment: What if you just change `-3` to `-2`?

Comment: This gives me too many significant figures 5 rather than 4 unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function:

```
Function RoundSignificant(ByVal dValue As Double, iFigures As Integer)
    Dim dSig As Double
    dSig = Abs(dValue)
    dSig = Application.Log10(dSig)
    dSig = 1 + Int(dSig)
    dSig = iFigures - dSig
    RoundSignificant = Round(dValue, dSig)
End Function


Sub test()
    Debug.Print RoundSignificant(0.000245848385, 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: So this works really well, as long as the 5th number is below 5. Anything more than that and it still rounds the 4th number up. 
If I have 0.000028348 it changes it to 0.00002835 rather than 0.00002834

Comment: Change `Round` to `Application.RoundDown`

Answer (score 0):

Using worksheet functions:

```
=VALUE(TEXT(compress,"0.000E+00"))
```

For VBA

```
CDbl(Format(compress,"0.000E+00"))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The VBA option also rounds the final value up rather than just removing the numbers after it

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to avoid rounding UP, but not rounding down, since rounding down should produce the exact result you want. So, instead of using VBA **Round** function, you could use Excel **WorksheetFunction.RoundDown** method to achieve the result you need.

ROUNDDOWN(0.0002458**6**548385;7)=0.000245800000
ROUNDDOWN(0.0002458**3**548385;7)=0.000245800000

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim compress As Double
compress = 0.000245858

Dim compressibility As Double
compressibility = Int(compress * 10 ^ -(Int(Log(Abs(compress))) - 3)) / 10 ^ -(Int(Log(Abs(compress))) - 3)

Debug.Print compressibility
End Sub
```